# Non correlated values on group by statement

Tags: mysql

Help me with next SQL:

```
SELECT
    date_format(from_unixtime(`ticket_logs`.`created`),'%Y-%m-%d') AS `datac`,
    `ticket_logs`.`ticket_id` AS `ticket_id`,
    ticket_logs.value_old,
    ticket_logs.value_new,
    max(`ticket_logs`.`action`) AS `ultima_act`

FROM
    `ticket_logs`
WHERE
    (
        (`ticket_logs`.`action` = 6)
        OR (`ticket_logs`.`action` = 16)
    )
GROUP BY
    date_format(
        from_unixtime(`ticket_logs`.`created`),
        '%Y-%m-%d'
    ),
    `ticket_logs`.`ticket_id`
ORDER BY
    `datac` DESC,
    `ticket_logs`.`ticket_id` DESC
```

The problem is that "value_old" and "value_new", always take the first value per date and not the value corresponding with the max value of "action"

Answer (score 0):

I don't see how this is a problem.  That is how SQL works -- the `order by` takes place *after* the `group by`.  In addition, MySQL is just confusing you, because you are using an extension to `group by` that you don't fully understand -- having extra columns in the `select` that are not in the `group by`.  (See [this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-extensions.html).)

Fortunately, MySQL supports a hack to get what you want, without writing a much more complicated SQL statement.  The expressions you want are:

```
substring_index(group_concat(ticket_logs.value_old order by `ticket_logs`.`action` desc), ',', 1)
substring_index(group_concat(ticket_logs.value_new order by `ticket_logs`.`action` desc), ',', 1)
```

Comment: Yes, thank you! I found some inner join examples but seems not to be appropriates to my problem. I'll test your solution. All the best!

Answer (score 0):

Found another approach. I used the "created" column to obtain a max and joined:

```
SELECT
    date_format(
        from_unixtime(`ticket_logs`.`created`),
        '%Y-%m-%d'
    ) AS `datax`,
    ticket_logs.ticket_id,
    ticket_logs.action,
    ticket_logs.value_old,
    ticket_logs.value_new
FROM
    ticket_logs
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT
        date_format(
            from_unixtime(`ticket_logs`.`created`),
            '%Y-%m-%d'
        ) AS `datac`,
        max(ticket_logs.created) AS maxts,
        ticket_id
    FROM
        ticket_logs
    WHERE
        ticket_logs.action = 6
    OR ticket_logs.action = 16
    GROUP BY
        date_format(
            from_unixtime(`ticket_logs`.`created`),
            '%Y-%m-%d'
        ),
        ticket_id
) maxtbl ON ticket_logs.ticket_id = maxtbl.ticket_id
AND ticket_logs.created = maxtbl.maxts
ORDER BY
    datax DESC,
    ticket_id DESC
```

Comment: `MAX(created)` is not the same thing as the "maximum value of action" which was specified in the question.

Comment: Yes, I know it is not the answer for my initial question. It is another approach for finding the value at the end of the day. It works in my context.